# Как выбрать номер блока в массиве по клику на блок в javascript?

Tags: javascript, slider

В данном примере необходимо при клике по блоку dot получить его номер и присвоить его slideIndex. Т.е. при клике по блоку dot переключался соответствующий слайд.
[вот pen](https://codepen.io/powerteks/pen/WayJeV)

```js
var prev = document.querySelector('.prev'),
  next = document.querySelector('.next'),
  slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
  dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot'),
slideIndex = 0;
showSlide(slideIndex);

prev.addEventListener('click', function(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex -= 1);
});
next.addEventListener('click', function(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex += 1);
});
//dot.addEventListener('click', function(n) {
//  showSlide(slideIndex = n);
//});

function showSlide(n) {
  var i
  if (n > slide.length - 1) {
    slideIndex = 0
  };
  if (n < 0) {
    slideIndex = slide.length - 1
  };
  for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dot.length; i++) {
    dot[i].classList.remove('view');
  }
  slide[slideIndex].classList.add('active');
  dot[slideIndex].classList.add('view');
};
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pad {
  width: 1000px;
  transform: translateX(-15%);
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slide1 {
  background: red;
}

.slide2 {
  background: green;
}

.slide3 {
  background: blue;
}

.slide4 {
  background: purple;
}

.slide5 {
  background: yellow;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.btns {
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn::before,
.btn::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.btn::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}

.btn::after {
  top: 29px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.next {
  margin-left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dots {
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  margin: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dot:hover,
.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.view:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>slider</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="pad">
          <div class="slide slide1 active"></div>
          <div class="slide slide2"></div>
          <div class="slide slide3"></div>
          <div class="slide slide4"></div>
          <div class="slide slide5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btns">
        <div class="btn prev"></div>
        <div class="btn next"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dots">
        <div class="dot view"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="dot"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var prev  = document.querySelector('.prev'),
    next  = document.querySelector('.next'),
    slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
    dot   = document.querySelectorAll('.dot'),
    slideIndex = 0;
    showSlide(slideIndex);

prev.addEventListener('click', function(n) {
     showSlide(slideIndex -= 1);
});
next.addEventListener('click', function(n) {
     showSlide(slideIndex += 1);
});
[...dot].forEach((dotEl, i) => dotEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    showSlide(slideIndex = i);
  })
);

function showSlide(n) {
  var i
  if ( n > slide.length-1) { slideIndex = 0 };
  if ( n < 0 ) { slideIndex = slide.length-1 };
  for ( i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  for ( i = 0; i < dot.length; i++) {
    dot[i].classList.remove('view');
  }
  slide[slideIndex].classList.add('active');
  dot[slideIndex].classList.add('view');
};
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 700px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pad {
  width: 1000px;
  transform: translateX(-15%);
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slide img {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.slide1 { background: red;}
.slide2 { background: green;}
.slide3 { background: blue;}
.slide4 { background: purple;}
.slide5 { background: yellow;}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.btns {
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn::before,
.btn::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.btn::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
.btn::after {
  top: 29px;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}

.next {
  margin-left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dots {
  text-align: center;
}

.dot {
  margin: 0 2px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dot:hover,
.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.view:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pad">
      <div class="slide active">
        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/27625/83cd4016-88ab-4862-83c1-add27caa11ba/s1200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/33827/b59ff485-e933-4b84-a9bf-e67115deaec9/s1200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
          <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/51720/dc5d2336-5cff-47ed-867d-d8aa63910b21/s1200" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/27625/777235b8-a4a3-49cb-bbe3-6e1100a7ee1c/s1200" alt="">
    </div>
      <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/28866/031f20dd-690d-468a-b019-f6b4be8f8420/s1200" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btns">
    <div class="btn prev"></div>
    <div class="btn next"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dots">
    <div class="dot view"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если не рефкторить ничего и не думать о нормальной реализации, то можно так, но я бы советовал:
 1. Использовать делегирование вместо добавления листенеров к каждому элементу
 2. Не хранить индекс активной точки в глобальной переменной, а использовать либо `data-` либо другой метод

Comment: Спасибо. Опыта в javascript почти нет. И поэтому мне интересно почитать или посмотреть на правильный вариант.